# extrair json dentro de resposta request

Tags: python, json, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.streamersonnew.world/list')
print(r.text)
```

dentro da variavel r, tem um json aprensentado como:

`<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">`

eu preciso pegar esse json, mas nao faço a minima ideia de como conseguir

Answer (score 0):

Use o [PyQuery](https://pypi.org/project/pyquery/)

`pip install pyquery`

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import json
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.streamersonnew.world/list')
html = pq(r.text)
jsoncode = html('script#__NEXT_DATA__').text()
result = json.loads(jsoncode)
```

O JSON retornado ficou salvo na variável `result`

Comment: caramba, show de bola. muito obrigado vou aproveitar e estudar esse pyquery

Comment: De nada, qualquer coisa só perguntar 

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa bem simples é usandoa biblioteca [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Exemplo:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.streamersonnew.world/list')

# Parce do response.text para html
html_base = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')

# Procura pela tag script com o id...
script = html_base.find('script', {'id':'__NEXT_DATA__'})

# Pega o conteúdo(string) da tag script encontrada
texto_do_script = script.string

print(json.loads(texto_do_script))
```